# Can't figure out how to install skater package in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install the 'Skater' package to enable model interpretation in Python.

I have tried installing it with `conda install -c conda-forge skater` and  `pip install -U skater` but I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skater'
```

whenever I try to use the following import statements:

```
from skater.core.explanations import Interpretation
from skater.model import InMemoryModel
```

Comment: Why are you using -u in the pip command? Shouldn't you just use `pip install skater`?

Comment: that's what the documentation for the package on github instructed to use

Comment: Okay, good to know. Are you sure you're using the same interpreter you installed this on in your code?

Comment: yup i'm positive.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: im using Python 3.9.5